# Running unix commands from Django

Tags: django, unix, wget

I have a Django site that is up and running.  I need to add a feature to call `wget` in response to a user action.  How should I do this from the Django application?

Answer (score 5):

Since Django is written in Python you can use Python's `subprocess` module to call `wget` in one of your views. However, if you merely want to download a file with `wget` (and not use one of its advanced features), you can emulate its behavior more easily with `urllib2`.

Comment: Also, if this operation is expensive, you must consider running the operation outside the request cycle, by using Celery, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you're resorting to a unix command, rather than using something like urllib2?

If there is, you can always use this within your view:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["wget", "http://myurl.com"])
```

Here's a pretty comprehensive thread on the matter:

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Celery](http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html)